# BTRFS - Subvolumes for / & /home, and being able to snapshot and restore from the snapshots?

Tags: arch-linux, btrfs

OS: Arch Linux x86_64

I have one BTRFS filesystem, both containing / & /home, how do I create subvolumes for both / & /home, and create a snapshot for each and restore from their snapshots (restore snapshots from a live CD)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Creating subvolumes for / and /home

Assuming / is currently the root subvolume of your BTRFS filesystem, you need to first create the subvolumes and then move the directories into their respective subvolumes.

**WARNING:** *Before* using any of the following commands, ensure you read about them and understand how they work.

```
cd /
btrfs subvol create rootfs
btrfs subvol create homefs
cp -a --reflink=always bin usr root var rootfs/ # This is just a sample of directories to copy. But DON'T copy home.
cp -a --reflink=always home/* homefs/
```

Then, edit `/etc/fstab` and change the / mountpoint so that it uses the rootfs subvolume. This is done by adding the option (-o) `subvol=rootfs`. Then, add a mountpoint for `/home` using the homefs subvolume. You'll also need to update the root filesystem configured in your bootloader.

Finally, reboot and confirm the new mountpoints are being used. If all is well, you can temporarily mount the root subvolume (in a directory such as /root/btrfs) and delete the original directories you copied.

## Creating snapshots

Personally, I have a subvolume containing my snapshots. That way I'm able to mount the snapshots at, say. `/mnt/snapshots` and have easy access to a file I may have accidently deleted.

### Setup

```
mkdir /root/btrfs
mount /dev/WHATEVER /root/btrfs
cd /root/btrfs
btrfs subvol create snapshots
```

### Example of taking a read-only snapshot

```
mount /dev/WHATEVER /root/btrfs
cd /root/btrfs
btrfs subvol snapshot -r rootfs snapshots/rootfs-2019-04-11
```

## Restoring from a snapshot

No LiveCD needed to restore from a snapshot. The process is quite simple: rename the subvolume and then create a read-write snapshot from the snapshot of your choosing.

### Example of restoring the rootfs snapshot.

```
mount /dev/WHATEVER /root/btrfs
cd /root/btrfs
mv rootfs rootfs-old # Even though rootfs would be mounted, you can still rename it without affecting the running system.
btrfs subvol snapshot snapshots/rootfs-2019-04-10 rootfs
```

Reboot for the restore to take effect.

Comment: When copying the sample directories (cp -a --reflink=always bin usr root var rootfs/), should I run it just like that or would it be a good idea to copy all directories in / (like etc, dev, proc, srv, opt)?

Comment: You'll need to recursively copy all the directories that are actually stored on your filesystem. For the virtual directories like /dev, /proc, and /run, you simply need to recreate the directories with the same permissions. An alternative method is to boot from a LiveCD/USB and mount the BTRFS filesystem; That would allow you to copy everything without accidently copying the virrual filesystems.

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa How are you getting that extra subvolume known as `rootfs` ? when I mount all I get is the entire rootfilesystem with `bin sys etc`. No subvolume in that.

Comment: If during installation you simply format a block device with btrfs and then use that as your root filesystem (as you'd do with say ext4) then you would have what you described; No additional subvolumes. Instead, you can create subvolumes (such as "rootfs") after creating the filesystem and use those subvolumes for any mountpoints you'd like, including the root filesystem. That's the approach I use because it offers more flexibility. It's even possible to dual-boot _some_ distros using the same btrfs filesystem; each distro would have it's own subvolume(s).